# How to monitor entire AWS environment?

Tags: amazon-web-services, monitoring, amazon-sns, amazon-cloudtrail

I am looking for a way to monitor any changes that occur to my production envrionment. Such as security group changes, ec2 create/stop/deletes, database changes, s3 bucket changes, route table changes, subnet changes, etc... I was looking at using cloudtrail for this and monitoring all api calls. However, when testing, my subscribed SNS topic was not receiving any notifications when i was making some changes for a test. Curious if anyone else has a work around for this or if I am missing something? Maybe lambda? Just looking for the easiest way to receive email notifications when any changes are made within my prod environment. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to audit the entire event history of AWS API calls then you would use CloudTrail, remembering to create a trail and enabling the options if you want to audit S3 or Lambda API calls.

By itself CloudTrail will provide auditing, but it can be combined with [CloudWatch](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/WhatIsCloudWatchEvents.html)/[EventBridge](https://aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/) to automate actions based on specific API calls such as triggering a Lambda or triggering an SNS topic.

Regarding your own implementation so far using SNS always ensure you've accepted the subscription first on the subscriber(s).

In addition you can use [AWS Config](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/config/latest/developerguide/WhatIsConfig.html) with many resources in AWS providing 2 benefits to you. You will be able to maintain a [history of changes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/config/latest/developerguide/view-manage-resource.html) to you resources, whilst also being able to [configure compliance and resolution rules](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/config/latest/developerguide/evaluate-config.html) for your resources.